# When connecting from A to C, through B, how can I specify PEM on B?

Tags: ssh, proxy

I am trying to connect to server C, through B. How can I provide the key for B?

i.e:

```
ssh -J sshtunnel@10.0.0.146:22[<-need to use PEM on B] root@10.0.2.123
```

sshtunnel's terminal is set to /bin/true - so I can authenticate, not login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file ~/.ssh/config with the content:

```
host 10.0.0.146
  HostName hostb
  IdentifyFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_hostb.pub
  User sshtunnel
```

Now you can use:

```
ssh -J 10.0.0.146 root@10.0.2.123
```

Comment: I am getting root@10.0.2.123: Permission denied (publickey). I should mention that the sshtunnel user - his terminal is set to /bin/true. I can authenticate, but not log into 10.0.0.146